# How to prevent triggering of onClick upon dragging and OnStart upon clicking when using react-draggable library in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, event-handling, draggable

```
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false)

const toggleOpen = (e) => {
   if(!dragging){
      setOpen(!open);
   }
}
const handleStart = (e) => {
   setDragging(true)
}
const handleStop = (e) => {
   setTimeout(function(){setDragging(false)},500);
}
<Draggable onDragStart={handleStart} onDragEnd={handleEnd}>
   open ?
      <SomeComponent>
      :
      null
   <Launcher onClick={toggleOpen} />
</Draggable>
```

upon clicking the `Launcher` component `onDragStart` and `onDragEnd` events are getting triggered and vice versa.
I tried all combinations of `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` and `return false` in all function calls but did not work. Someway i need to keep these events separate, user should be able to click `Launcher` component and `SomeComponent` should appear. Also user should be able to drag `Launcher` but when finished dragging `SomeComponent` should not appear.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here: https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-draggable/issues/49#issuecomment-517212934

```js
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false)

const handleStart = () => {
  setDragging(true);
};

const handleStop = () => {
  setTimeout(function(){setDragging(false)},500);
  if (!dragging) {
    setOpen(!open);
  }
};

<Draggable onDrag={handleStart} onStop={handleStop}>
   open ?
      <SomeComponent>
      :
      null
   <Launcher />
</Draggable>
```

I'm assuming here that `Launcher` is the only clickable component inside `Draggable` so a click on `Draggable` is equivalent to a click on `Launcher`